# IProgress Error while material query via MPRester

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymatgen, iprogress

I am using python 3.8 in `spyder3`. I am getting an error while doing:

```
mp=MPRester('api key')

data = mp.query(criteria={}, properties=['task_id']) #this line raises error
```

The error is :

```
NameError: name '**IProgress**' is not defined.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
ImportError: **FloatProgress** not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets.
```

But I'm not working with **Jupyter notebook** and **ipywidgets** is updated. This problem doesn't happen while working in **Google collab**.

Answer (score 2):

Installing these two worked for me:

```
pip install ipywidgets IProgress
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not answering the error but showing a worked script for me. Using the following approach might help.

```py
from pymatgen import MPRester
api = MPRester("your key")

# criteria you want
criteria={"elements":{"$all": ["O"]}, "nelements":{'$lt':4}}

# properties you want
properties = ["pretty_formula", "cif", "material_id"]

c = api.query(criteria=criteria,properties=properties)
```